# Can an OP request that earned points be deducted?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, up-votes

I recently deleted my answer to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61942/5275) because I was proven wrong. Meanwhile, I earned upvotes. Is there a way to get these votes deducted, as I feel that I did not deserve them?

Comment: dupe? http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3687/759

Answer (score 4):

If a post has a net score of less than 3 or has been on the site for fewer than 60 days, when the post is deleted the reputation it produced is also removed.  This might not happen immediately; it could take until the next day (UTC).  Your answer was at +2 when deleted so you should see an adjustment.

If those conditions aren't met, I don't think you can have the rep changes undone.  The reason is that, in general, if your post was live for that long and upvoted enough then it did help people, even if later conditions changed and the post was removed -- site rules or scope changed, a better answer came along and you want to defer, things changed and invalidated a once-correct answer (more likely on the technical sites than here), etc.

If you feel like you have undeserved reputation, you might consider lowering it, while helping the site, by offering a bounty.  I've sometimes done this to reward existing answers that I feel have been under-valued by the community.  We have a lot of great answers, so if you're feeling too reputation-rich I'm confident you can find a place to spend some of it.

Comment: "if you're feeling too reputation-rich I'm confident you can find a place to spend some of it".  Gee, thanks for deflating my ego ;-) Shabbat Shalom & stay cool in Pitt.

Comment: @DanF I had no intention to deflate your ego and am not sure what you're seeing.  I'm sorry for giving that impression.  You seemed to be saying that you felt you didn't deserve the rep, and I was trying to honor that and suggest a different path to adjusting it if that's what you wanted.  Shabbat shalom!

Comment: Monica - I was joking ... relax! "Moderation" may be getting to you ;-) I like the bounty suggestion, BTW. Though, lately, a few of my bounties didn't even get a comment. I think I've been asking stumpers!

Comment: @DanF that's the beauty of the "reward existing answer" bounty reason -- you can find something that you already know is worthy of attention, call attention to it, and award a bounty.  I, too, have offered several bounties on unanswered questions that still failed to attract answers.  It's disappointing when that happens.

Answer (score 2):

Per

[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that):

> Reputation changes from bounties, votes (both up and down), and acceptances on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified. (Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of three or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained).

You're all set. It may take a little time for your reputation total to change, due to caching.